# Why does /etc/profile check PS1 rather than the -i flag in $-

Tags: startup, dot-files

I know of two ways to test whether a shell is interactive,

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo "-i option flag indicates interactive"

[ -n "$PS1" ] && echo "prompt is set"
```

I've read that checking for the `i` option flag is more reliable, which makes sense given that it's an explicit indicator of interactivity.

But when I look through the startup files on my system (e.g. `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`), they check `PS1`. I'm running Ubuntu. I don't know how platform-specific this is.

I'm wondering whether this means:

- the authors of the startup files are not as skilled as I assumed
- `PS1` is reliable enough in this context
- `PS1` is reliable enough in general, and I'm overthinking things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 system, this is the check in [`/etc/profile`](https://git.launchpad.net/~usd-import-team/ubuntu/+source/base-files/tree/share/profile?h=ubuntu/xenial):

```sh
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi
```

... which seems to me is mostly concerned about setting `PS1` (and not for controlling the behaviour of the rest of the rc file). I don't see how testing for `-i` would help in that.

Comment: That's a good point. Have a look at `/etc/bash.bashrc` though.

Comment: @ivan hmmm. In that case, I'd note that checking `PS1` for bash should be equivalent - since bash unsets `PS1` if not interactive (compare `PS1=foo bash --noprofile --norc -c 'echo $PS1'` vs `PS1=foo bash --noprofile --norc -ic 'echo $PS1'`). Also: [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) treats both as equally valid.